# Как правильно настроить редирект с www на без www?

Tags: wordpress

мой файл htaccess

```
# BEGIN All In One WP Security
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_WP_FILE_ACCESS_START
<Files license.txt>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
<Files wp-config-sample.php>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
<Files readme.html>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_WP_FILE_ACCESS_END
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files .htaccess>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
ServerSignature Off
LimitRequestBody 10485760
<Files wp-config.php>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_PINGBACK_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files xmlrpc.php>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_PINGBACK_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_DEBUG_LOG_BLOCK_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files debug.log>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_DEBUG_LOG_BLOCK_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_INDEX_VIEWS_START
Options -Indexes
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_INDEX_VIEWS_END
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_TRACE_TRACK_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_TRACE_TRACK_END
#AIOWPS_FORBID_PROXY_COMMENTS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:FORWARDED} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:USERAGENT_VIA} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_HOST} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROXY_CONNECTION} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:XPROXY_CONNECTION} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP} !^$
RewriteRule wp-comments-post\.php - [F]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_FORBID_PROXY_COMMENTS_END
#AIOWPS_DENY_BAD_QUERY_STRINGS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp:     [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http:    [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https:   [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\;|'|\"|%22).*(request|insert|union|declare|drop) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_DENY_BAD_QUERY_STRINGS_END
#AIOWPS_ADVANCED_CHAR_STRING_FILTER_START
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 403 \,
RedirectMatch 403 \:
RedirectMatch 403 \;
RedirectMatch 403 \=
RedirectMatch 403 \[
RedirectMatch 403 \]
RedirectMatch 403 \^
RedirectMatch 403 \`
RedirectMatch 403 \{
RedirectMatch 403 \}
RedirectMatch 403 \~
RedirectMatch 403 \"
RedirectMatch 403 \$
RedirectMatch 403 \<
RedirectMatch 403 \>
RedirectMatch 403 \|
RedirectMatch 403 \.\.
RedirectMatch 403 \%0
RedirectMatch 403 \%A
RedirectMatch 403 \%B
RedirectMatch 403 \%C
RedirectMatch 403 \%D
RedirectMatch 403 \%E
RedirectMatch 403 \%F
RedirectMatch 403 \%22
RedirectMatch 403 \%27
RedirectMatch 403 \%28
RedirectMatch 403 \%29
RedirectMatch 403 \%3C
RedirectMatch 403 \%3E
RedirectMatch 403 \%3F
RedirectMatch 403 \%5B
RedirectMatch 403 \%5C
RedirectMatch 403 \%5D
RedirectMatch 403 \%7B
RedirectMatch 403 \%7C
RedirectMatch 403 \%7D
# COMMON PATTERNS
Redirectmatch 403 \_vpi
RedirectMatch 403 \.inc
Redirectmatch 403 xAou6
Redirectmatch 403 db\_name
Redirectmatch 403 select\(
Redirectmatch 403 convert\(
Redirectmatch 403 \/query\/
RedirectMatch 403 ImpEvData
Redirectmatch 403 \.XMLHTTP
Redirectmatch 403 proxydeny
RedirectMatch 403 function\.
Redirectmatch 403 remoteFile
Redirectmatch 403 servername
Redirectmatch 403 \&rptmode\=
Redirectmatch 403 sys\_cpanel
RedirectMatch 403 db\_connect
RedirectMatch 403 doeditconfig
RedirectMatch 403 check\_proxy
Redirectmatch 403 system\_user
Redirectmatch 403 \/\(null\)\/
Redirectmatch 403 clientrequest
Redirectmatch 403 option\_value
RedirectMatch 403 ref\.outcontrol
# SPECIFIC EXPLOITS
RedirectMatch 403 errors\.
RedirectMatch 403 config\.
RedirectMatch 403 include\.
RedirectMatch 403 display\.
RedirectMatch 403 register\.
Redirectmatch 403 password\.
RedirectMatch 403 maincore\.
RedirectMatch 403 authorize\.
Redirectmatch 403 macromates\.
RedirectMatch 403 head\_auth\.
RedirectMatch 403 submit\_links\.
RedirectMatch 403 change\_action\.
Redirectmatch 403 com\_facileforms\/
RedirectMatch 403 admin\_db\_utilities\.
RedirectMatch 403 admin\.webring\.docs\.
Redirectmatch 403 Table\/Latest\/index\.
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_ADVANCED_CHAR_STRING_FILTER_END
#AIOWPS_FIVE_G_BLACKLIST_START
# 5G BLACKLIST/FIREWALL (2013)
# @ http://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/

# 5G:[QUERY STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\"|%22).*(<|>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (javascript:).*(\;) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\\|\.\./|`|='$|=%27$) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\;|'|\"|%22).*(union|select|insert|drop|update|md5|benchmark|or|and|if) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (base64_encode|localhost|mosconfig) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (boot\.ini|echo.*kae|etc/passwd) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (GLOBALS|REQUEST)(=|\[|%) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 5G:[USER AGENTS]
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
# SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ^$ keep_out
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (binlar|casper|cmsworldmap|comodo|diavol|dotbot|feedfinder|flicky|ia_archiver|jakarta|kmccrew|nutch|planetwork|purebot|pycurl|skygrid|sucker|turnit|vikspider|zmeu) keep_out
<limit GET POST PUT>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=keep_out
</limit>
</IfModule>

# 5G:[REQUEST STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 403 (https?|ftp|php)\://
RedirectMatch 403 /(https?|ima|ucp)/
RedirectMatch 403 /(Permanent|Better)$
RedirectMatch 403 (\=\\\'|\=\\%27|/\\\'/?|\)\.css\()$
RedirectMatch 403 (\,|\)\+|/\,/|\{0\}|\(/\(|\.\.\.|\+\+\+|\||\\\"\\\")
RedirectMatch 403 \.(cgi|asp|aspx|cfg|dll|exe|jsp|mdb|sql|ini|rar)$
RedirectMatch 403 /(contac|fpw|install|pingserver|register)\.php$
RedirectMatch 403 (base64|crossdomain|localhost|wwwroot|e107\_)
RedirectMatch 403 (eval\(|\_vti\_|\(null\)|echo.*kae|config\.xml)
RedirectMatch 403 \.well\-known/host\-meta
RedirectMatch 403 /function\.array\-rand
RedirectMatch 403 \)\;\$\(this\)\.html\(
RedirectMatch 403 proc/self/environ
RedirectMatch 403 msnbot\.htm\)\.\_
RedirectMatch 403 /ref\.outcontrol
RedirectMatch 403 com\_cropimage
RedirectMatch 403 indonesia\.htm
RedirectMatch 403 \{\$itemURL\}
RedirectMatch 403 function\(\)
RedirectMatch 403 labels\.rdf
RedirectMatch 403 /playing.php
RedirectMatch 403 muieblackcat
</IfModule>

# 5G:[REQUEST METHOD]
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_FIVE_G_BLACKLIST_END
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_SPAMBOTS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-comments-post\.php(.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(.*)?\.vasyaznaet\.ru [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1 [L]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_SPAMBOTS_END
#AIOWPS_PREVENT_IMAGE_HOTLINKS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(.*)?\.vasyaznaet\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_PREVENT_IMAGE_HOTLINKS_END
# END All In One WP Security

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

FileETag MTime Size
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
<filesmatch ".(jpg|gif|png|css|js)$">
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</filesmatch>
</ifmodule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
# Директивы (строки) между `BEGIN WordPress` и `END WordPress`
# созданы автоматически и подлежат изменению только через фильтры WordPress.
# Сделанные вручную изменения между этими маркерами будут перезаписаны.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Как правильно настроить редирект?

сейчас когда захожу на сайт по адресу [www.site.ru](http://www.site.ru) выдает

```
Не удается получить доступ к сайтуПроверьте, нет ли опечаток в имени хоста www.vasyaznaet.ru.
Если все правильно, воспользуйтесь инструментом "Диагностика сетей Windows".
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

Comment: Вероятно это тот редкий случай, когда это разные каталоги, и в таком случае хтацесс не поможет. Нужно на сервере сделать алиас. А остальное ВП всё сам сделает (проверь в админке правильнось написания адресов).

Comment: адреса одинаковые Адрес WordPress (URL) и Адрес сайта (URL)

Comment: Сервер настраивай.

Comment: там обычный хостинг

Comment: Вот ты зачем это говоришь? Проблема не с ВП, проблема на сервере. Ида "обычный хостинг" тоже настраивается. И что именно надо сделать я тебе сказал. Не можешь - обращайся к хостеру.